# JSON format Invalid while doing json_encode in PHP

Tags: php, json

When i tried to display a JSON decoded response i got this JSON. But it returned invalid format.

I tried the same in http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/ and it also returned error.

Why is this error happening even if i tried to add addslashes() and htmlspecialchars function...

Any help is appreciated......

```
{"data":[{"id":"ZGRlBQR9ac3K","type":1,"title":"asasasas edieddddd","feed":{"is_img":0},"c_date":"2014-04-24 10:22:14","owner":"Joffin Joy","owner_first":"Joffin","owner_id":"ZGN0AQZ9ac3K","owner_type":"FH5R","photo":"http:\/\/localhost\/4thUser_v4\/images\/getuserphoto\/ZGN0AQZ9ac3K\/1\/small\/10443_1395738251_usr_crop.jpg","lc_cnt":[{"like":"1","comment":"6"}],"ckt_name":{"ZwVk":"Trainees"},"comments":{"ZwVk":[{"uc_id":"AQp1AN=9ac3K","uc_c_date":"2014-04-24 10:26:57","uc_m_date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","comment":"dfdfdfdf","comment_type":"1","sender_type":"0","user_id":"ZGN0AQZ9ac3K","display_name":"Joffin Joy","u_type":"FH5R","photo":"http:\/\/localhost\/4thUser_v4\/images\/getuserphoto\/ZGN0AQZ9ac3K\/1\/small\/10443_1395738251_usr_crop.jpg","like_cnt":"1"}]}},{"id":"ZGNkZwN9ac3K","type":6,"title":"tlk","desc":"sdfsdfsdf","c_date":"2014-04-23 20:28:27","author_name":"Herald Charley","about_author":"sdfsdfsdf","authorId":"ZGNjAmD9ac3K","owner_first":"Sanesh","owner":"Sanesh Sunny","owner_id":"ZGNjBQN9ac3K","owner_type":"FH5R","photo":"http:\/\/localhost\/4thUser_v4\/images\/getuserphoto\/ZGNjBQN9ac3K\/1\/small\/noimage-ind.jpg","author_photo":"http:\/\/localhost\/4thUser_v4\/images\/getuserphoto\/ZGNjAmD9ac3K\/1\/small\/10074_1398168441_usr_lr.","lc_cnt":[{"like":"0","comment":"5"}],"ckt_name":{"ZwVk":"Trainees"},"comments":{"ZwVk":[{"uc_id":"AQp1BD=9ac3K","uc_c_date":"2014-04-24 19:23:15","uc_m_date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","comment":"testing...","comment_type":"1","sender_type":"0","user_id":"ZGNkZwH9ac3K","display_name":"User Jolly","u_type":"FH5R","photo":"http:\/\/localhost\/4thUser_v4\/images\/getuserphoto\/ZGNkZwH9ac3K\/1\/small\/10125_1398517242_usr_crop.JPG","like_cnt":"0"},{"uc_id":"AQp2Aj=9ac3K","uc_c_date":"2014-04-25 12:48:41","uc_m_date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","comment":"<script>alert('asdasdas')<\/script>","comment_type":"1","sender_type":"0","user_id":"ZGNkZwH9ac3K","display_name":"User Jolly","u_type":"FH5R","photo":"http:\/\/localhost\/4thUser_v4\/images\/getuserphoto\/ZGNkZwH9ac3K\/1\/small\/10125_1398517242_usr_crop.JPG","like_cnt":"0"},{"uc_id":"AQp3Aj=9ac3K","uc_c_date":"2014-04-27 19:45:05","uc_m_date":"2014-04-27 19:45:32","comment":"test comment123456789","comment_type":"1","sender_type":"0","user_id":"ZGNjAGx9ac3K","display_name":"Arungopan Gopakumar","u_type":"FH5R","photo":"http:\/\/localhost\/4thUser_v4\/images\/getuserphoto\/ZGNjAGx9ac3K\/1\/small\/10059_1398933445_usr_crop.jpg","like_cnt":"1"}]}},{"id":"ZGNlBGD9ac3K","type":7,"title":"jkhkhjk df sdfsdfdsfdsfsfdsf","source":"http:\/\/www.lipsum.com\/feed\/htmlhttp:\/\/www.lipsum.com\/feed\/htmlhttp:\/\/www.lipsum.com\/feed\/htmlhttp:\/\/www.lipsum.com\/feed\/htmlhttp:\/\/www.lipsum.com\/feed\/htmlhttp:\/\/www.lipsum.com\/feed\/html","c_date":"2014-04-22 12:53:17","summary":"","owner_first":"Joffin","owner":"Joffin Joy","owner_id":"ZGN0AQZ9ac3K","owner_type":"FH5R","photo":"http:\/\/localhost\/4thUser_v4\/images\/getuserphoto\/ZGN0AQZ9ac3K\/1\/small\/10443_1395738251_usr_crop.jpg","lc_cnt":[{"like":"0","comment":"7"}],"ckt_name":{"ZwVk":"Trainees"},"comments":{"ZwVk":[{"uc_id":"AQL2Aj=9ac3K","uc_c_date":"2014-04-22 13:07:42","uc_m_date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","comment":"<script>alert('asdsadasdsa'"'''")<\/script>","comment_type":"1","sender_type":"0","user_id":"ZGNkZwH9ac3K","display_name":"User Jolly","u_type":"FH5R","photo":"http:\/\/localhost\/4thUser_v4\/images\/getuserphoto\/ZGNkZwH9ac3K\/1\/small\/10125_1398517242_usr_crop.JPG","like_cnt":"0"},{"uc_id":"AQL2BN=9ac3K","uc_c_date":"2014-04-22 13:08:09","uc_m_date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","comment":"<script>alert('asdsadasdsa')<\/script>","comment_type":"1","sender_type":"0","user_id":"ZGNkZwH9ac3K","display_name":"User Jolly","u_type":"FH5R","photo":"http:\/\/localhost\/4thUser_v4\/images\/getuserphoto\/ZGNkZwH9ac3K\/1\/small\/10125_1398517242_usr_crop.JPG","like_cnt":"0"},{"uc_id":"AQL2BD=9ac3K","uc_c_date":"2014-04-22 13:10:06","uc_m_date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","comment":"<script>alert('helloooo checking....');<\/script>","comment_type":"1","sender_type":"0","user_id":"ZGNkZwH9ac3K","display_name":"User Jolly","u_type":"FH5R","photo":"http:\/\/localhost\/4thUser_v4\/images\/getuserphoto\/ZGNkZwH9ac3K\/1\/small\/10125_1398517242_usr_crop.JPG","like_cnt":"0"}]}},{"id":"ZGRlZGL9ac3K","type":1,"title":"sample postApr 21 22014...edited sxdsdasdasdasdasdasdd\r\n\r\nLorem ipsum .","feed":{"is_img":0},"c_date":"2014-04-21 17:19:19","owner":"Joffin Joy","owner_first":"Joffin","owner_id":"ZGN0AQZ9ac3K","owner_type":"FH5R","photo":"http:\/\/localhost\/4thUser_v4\/images\/getuserphoto\/ZGN0AQZ9ac3K\/1\/small\/10443_1395738251_usr_crop.jpg","lc_cnt":null,"ckt_name":{"ZwVk":"Trainees"}},{"id":"ZGNlZGD9ac3K","type":2,"title":"sample event Apr 21 2014.....","desc":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas adipiscing diam elit, ac pharetra magna rhoncus id. Quisque placerat imperdiet dolor in varius.","st_date":"Apr 21, 2014","st_time":"20:30:00","end_date":"May 14, 2014","end_time":"15:00:00","location":"Long Beach, CA, United States","c_date":"2014-04-21 17:15:10","owner_first":"Joffin","owner":"Joffin Joy","owner_id":"ZGN0AQZ9ac3K","owner_type":"FH5R","photo":"http:\/\/localhost\/4thUser_v4\/images\/getuserphoto\/ZGN0AQZ9ac3K\/1\/small\/10443_1395738251_usr_crop.jpg","lc_cnt":null,"ckt_name":{"ZwVk":"Trainees"}},{"id":"ZGNkBQx9ac3K","type":2,"title":"evnt on 17th april(edited)","desc":"description field\r\n~!@#$%^&*()_+\/\\'"\u3053\u3093\u306b\u3061\u306fHallå\u4f60\u597d\u0928\u092e\u0938\u094d\u0924\u0947\r\nalert('hello");","st_date":"Jan 02, 2010","st_time":"10:05:00","end_date":"Apr 17, 2014","end_time":"10:05:00","location":"Mobile, AL, United States","c_date":"2014-04-17 10:05:28","owner_first":"Sanesh","owner":"Sanesh Sunny","owner_id":"ZGNjBQN9ac3K","owner_type":"FH5R","photo":"http:\/\/localhost\/4thUser_v4\/images\/getuserphoto\/ZGNjBQN9ac3K\/1\/small\/noimage-ind.jpg","lc_cnt":[{"like":"1","comment":"3"}],"ckt_name":{"ZwVk":"Trainees"},"comments":{"ZwVk":[{"uc_id":"AQLjZD=9ac3K","uc_c_date":"2014-04-17 11:07:42","uc_m_date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","comment":"sdsds","comment_type":"1","sender_type":"0","user_id":"ZGR9ac3K","display_name":"User User Technologies Pvt Ltd","u_type":"D09F","photo":"http:\/\/localhost\/4thUser_v4\/images\/getuserphoto\/ZGR9ac3K\/1\/small\/1398519087_11.jpg","like_cnt":"0"},{"uc_id":"AQLkZN=9ac3K","uc_c_date":"2014-04-17 11:44:35","uc_m_date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","comment":"sdfsdfsdfsdf","comment_type":"1","sender_type":"0","user_id":"ZGNjAmD9ac3K","display_name":"Herald Charley","u_type":"FH5R","photo":"http:\/\/localhost\/4thUser_v4\/images\/getuserphoto\/ZGNjAmD9ac3K\/1\/small\/10074_1398168441_usr_lr.","like_cnt":"0"},{"uc_id":"AQLkZD=9ac3K","uc_c_date":"2014-04-17 11:44:45","uc_m_date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","comment":"sdfsdfsdfsdf","comment_type":"1","sender_type":"0","user_id":"ZGNjAmD9ac3K","display_name":"Herald Charley","u_type":"FH5R","photo":"http:\/\/localhost\/4thUser_v4\/images\/getuserphoto\/ZGNjAmD9ac3K\/1\/small\/10074_1398168441_usr_lr.","like_cnt":"0"}]}},{"id":"ZGRkAmN9ac3K","type":1,"title":"test post by sanesh on 16th april and shared with trainees ckt","feed":{"is_img":0},"c_date":"2014-04-16 14:10:56","owner":"Sanesh Sunny","owner_first":"Sanesh","owner_id":"ZGNjBQN9ac3K","owner_type":"FH5R","photo":"http:\/\/localhost\/4thUser_v4\/images\/getuserphoto\/ZGNjBQN9ac3K\/1\/small\/noimage-ind.jpg","lc_cnt":[{"like":"0","comment":"1"}],"ckt_name":{"ZwVk":"Trainees"}},{"id":"ZGRkAmD9ac3K","type":1,"title":"edited","feed":{"is_img":0},"c_date":"2014-04-16 14:21:23","owner":"Sanesh Sunny","owner_first":"Sanesh","owner_id":"ZGNjBQN9ac3K","owner_type":"FH5R","photo":"http:\/\/localhost\/4thUser_v4\/images\/getuserphoto\/ZGNjBQN9ac3K\/1\/small\/noimage-ind.jpg","lc_cnt":[{"like":"0","comment":"9"}],"ckt_name":{"ZwVk":"Trainees"},"comments":{"ZwVk":[{"uc_id":"AQH3BD=9ac3K","uc_c_date":"2014-04-16 15:31:41","uc_m_date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","comment":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam et malesuada libero. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. ","comment_type":"1","sender_type":"0","user_id":"ZGNjBQN9ac3K","display_name":"Sanesh Sunny","u_type":"FH5R","photo":"http:\/\/localhost\/4thUser_v4\/images\/getuserphoto\/ZGNjBQN9ac3K\/1\/small\/noimage-ind.jpg","like_cnt":"0"},{"uc_id":"AQH4Aj=9ac3K","uc_c_date":"2014-04-16 18:42:38","uc_m_date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","comment":"~!@#$%^&*()_+\/\\'"\u3053\u3093\u306b\u3061\u306fHallå\u4f60\u597d\u0928\u092e\u0938\u094d\u0924\u0947","comment_type":"1","sender_type":"0","user_id":"ZGNjBQN9ac3K","display_name":"Sanesh Sunny","u_type":"FH5R","photo":"http:\/\/localhost\/4thUser_v4\/images\/getuserphoto\/ZGNjBQN9ac3K\/1\/small\/noimage-ind.jpg","like_cnt":"0"}]}},{"id":"ZGNjAmx9ac3K","type":6,"title":"Sample Talk Added Apr 14 2014.....","desc":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In posuere elit odio, vel interdum ligula pretium vitae. Praesent eu orci non ipsum euismod mollis. ","c_date":"2014-04-14 18:34:44","author_name":"Sanesh Sunny","about_author":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In posuere elit odio,","authorId":"ZGNjBQN9ac3K","owner_first":"Joffin","owner":"Joffin Joy","owner_id":"ZGN0AQZ9ac3K","owner_type":"FH5R","photo":"http:\/\/localhost\/4thUser_v4\/images\/getuserphoto\/ZGN0AQZ9ac3K\/1\/small\/10443_1395738251_usr_crop.jpg","author_photo":"http:\/\/localhost\/4thUser_v4\/images\/getuserphoto\/ZGNjBQN9ac3K\/1\/small\/noimage-ind.jpg","lc_cnt":null,"ckt_name":{"ZwVk":"Trainees"}},{"id":"ZGRjAGR9ac3K","type":1,"title":"I amsdsdsdsdsd co-founder ofsdsdsds da","feed":{"is_img":0},"c_date":"2014-03-08 07:47:22","owner":"User Jolly","owner_first":"User","owner_id":"ZGNkZwH9ac3K","owner_type":"FH5R","photo":"http:\/\/localhost\/4thUser_v4\/images\/getuserphoto\/ZGNkZwH9ac3K\/1\/small\/10125_1398517242_usr_crop.JPG","lc_cnt":[{"like":"1","comment":"0"}],"ckt_name":{"ZGD3AQZ9ac3K":"Vijayee Bhava"}},{"id":"ZGRjAQx9ac3K","type":1,"title":"Lessons on Self Development\r\nhttp:\/\/localhost\/files\/vijayeebhava\/2\/Vijayeebhava_Lessons_Self_development.pptx\r\n\r\nPrepared by: Sreeja - Phoenix team","feed":{"is_img":0},"c_date":"2014-03-09 10:26:18","owner":"Vijayee Bhava","owner_first":"Vijayee Bhava","owner_id":"AQL2ZwL9ac3K","owner_type":"D09F","photo":"http:\/\/localhost\/4thUser_v4\/images\/getuserphoto\/AQL2ZwL9ac3K\/1\/small\/1394201730_46626.png","lc_cnt":[{"like":"1","comment":"0"}],"ckt_name":{"ZGD3AQH9ac3K":"Vijayee Bhava - II"}},{"id":"ZGNlAmL9ac3K","type":7,"title":"Key Lessons on LEADERSHIP","desc":"https:\/\/localhost\/files\/vijayeebhava\/2\/Vijayeebhava_Leadership_Key_Lessons.docx <\/a>","source":"","c_date":"2014-03-08 20:40:55","summary":"","owner_first":"Anaz","owner":"Anaz Kabeer","owner_id":"ZGNmZQH9ac3K","owner_type":"FH5R","photo":"http:\/\/localhost\/4thUser_v4\/images\/getuserphoto\/ZGNmZQH9ac3K\/1\/small\/10305_1382457349_usr_lr.","lc_cnt":[{"like":"1","comment":"0"}],"ckt_name":{"ZGD3AQH9ac3K":"Vijayee Bhava - II"}},{"id":"ZGNlAmp9ac3K","type":7,"title":"Qualities of an Entrepreneur","desc":"https:\/\/localhost\/files\/vijayeebhava\/2\/Vijayeebhava_Key_Lessons_Qualities_Entrepreneur.docx <\/a>","source":"","c_date":"2014-03-08 20:41:37","summary":"","owner_first":"Anaz","owner":"Anaz Kabeer","owner_id":"ZGNmZQH9ac3K","owner_type":"FH5R","photo":"http:\/\/localhost\/4thUser_v4\/images\/getuserphoto\/ZGNmZQH9ac3K\/1\/small\/10305_1382457349_usr_lr.","lc_cnt":[{"like":"1","comment":"0"}],"ckt_name":{"ZGD3AQH9ac3K":"Vijayee Bhava - II"}}],"tp_likes":"[id=\"tp_like_ZGNlAmL9ac3K_7_T\"],[id=\"tp_like_ZGNlAmp9ac3K_7_T\"],[id=\"tp_like_ZGRjAQx9ac3K_1_T\"],[id=\"tp_like_ZGRlBQR9ac3K_1_T\"]","cmnt_likes":"[id=\"tp_like_ZGRlBQR9ac3K_1_AQp1AN=9ac3K_C\"]","up_next":"2014-03-09 09:14:44","up_start":0,"up_end":"15"}
```

Comment: Yep, your `JSON` is invalid. Use [this tool](http://jsonlint.com/) to check for errors

Comment: any idea this is happening or bypass this error i have been trying this for quite long time?

Comment: Could be on <script>alert('asdsadasdasa'"'</script> part. Double quotes are not escaped there. I just notice its not colored correctly on that part.

Comment: try strip_tags() then json_encode()

Comment: as i need to show <script> tags as it is.. i can't use strip_tags()...

Comment: can you show actual code before encoded

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot of Javascript in that JSON, and the double quotes in the `alert()`'s are whats making it invalid.

Paste your string in there, it shows you everything that's invalid

http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#jsonformatter

For reference I removed all the invalid parts, this string is valid JSON

```
{"data":[{"id":"ZGRlBQR9ac3K","type":1,"title":"asasasas edieddddd","feed":{"is_img":0},"c_date":"2014-04-24 10:22:14","owner":"Joffin Joy","owner_first":"Joffin","owner_id":"ZGN0AQZ9ac3K","owner_type":"FH5R","photo":"http:\/\/localhost\/4thUser_v4\/images\/getuserphoto\/ZGN0AQZ9ac3K\/1\/small\/10443_1395738251_usr_crop.jpg","lc_cnt":[{"like":"1","comment":"6"}],"ckt_name":{"ZwVk":"Trainees"},"comments":{"ZwVk":[{"uc_id":"AQp1AN=9ac3K","uc_c_date":"2014-04-24 10:26:57","uc_m_date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","comment":"dfdfdfdf","comment_type":"1","sender_type":"0","user_id":"ZGN0AQZ9ac3K","display_name":"Joffin Joy","u_type":"FH5R","photo":"http:\/\/localhost\/4thUser_v4\/images\/getuserphoto\/ZGN0AQZ9ac3K\/1\/small\/10443_1395738251_usr_crop.jpg","like_cnt":"1"}]}},{"id":"ZGNkZwN9ac3K","type":6,"title":"tlk","desc":"sdfsdfsdf","c_date":"2014-04-23 20:28:27","author_name":"Herald Charley","about_author":"sdfsdfsdf","authorId":"ZGNjAmD9ac3K","owner_first":"Sanesh","owner":"Sanesh Sunny","owner_id":"ZGNjBQN9ac3K","owner_type":"FH5R","photo":"http:\/\/localhost\/4thUser_v4\/images\/getuserphoto\/ZGNjBQN9ac3K\/1\/small\/noimage-ind.jpg","author_photo":"http:\/\/localhost\/4thUser_v4\/images\/getuserphoto\/ZGNjAmD9ac3K\/1\/small\/10074_1398168441_usr_lr.","lc_cnt":[{"like":"0","comment":"5"}],"ckt_name":{"ZwVk":"Trainees"},"comments":{"ZwVk":[{"uc_id":"AQp1BD=9ac3K","uc_c_date":"2014-04-24 19:23:15","uc_m_date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","comment":"testing...","comment_type":"1","sender_type":"0","user_id":"ZGNkZwH9ac3K","display_name":"User Jolly","u_type":"FH5R","photo":"http:\/\/localhost\/4thUser_v4\/images\/getuserphoto\/ZGNkZwH9ac3K\/1\/small\/10125_1398517242_usr_crop.JPG","like_cnt":"0"},{"uc_id":"AQp2Aj=9ac3K","uc_c_date":"2014-04-25 12:48:41","uc_m_date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","comment":"","comment_type":"1","sender_type":"0","user_id":"ZGNkZwH9ac3K","display_name":"User Jolly","u_type":"FH5R","photo":"http:\/\/localhost\/4thUser_v4\/images\/getuserphoto\/ZGNkZwH9ac3K\/1\/small\/10125_1398517242_usr_crop.JPG","like_cnt":"0"},{"uc_id":"AQp3Aj=9ac3K","uc_c_date":"2014-04-27 19:45:05","uc_m_date":"2014-04-27 19:45:32","comment":"test comment123456789","comment_type":"1","sender_type":"0","user_id":"ZGNjAGx9ac3K","display_name":"Arungopan Gopakumar","u_type":"FH5R","photo":"http:\/\/localhost\/4thUser_v4\/images\/getuserphoto\/ZGNjAGx9ac3K\/1\/small\/10059_1398933445_usr_crop.jpg","like_cnt":"1"}]}},{"id":"ZGNlBGD9ac3K","type":7,"title":"jkhkhjk df sdfsdfdsfdsfsfdsf","source":"http:\/\/www.lipsum.com\/feed\/htmlhttp:\/\/www.lipsum.com\/feed\/htmlhttp:\/\/www.lipsum.com\/feed\/htmlhttp:\/\/www.lipsum.com\/feed\/htmlhttp:\/\/www.lipsum.com\/feed\/htmlhttp:\/\/www.lipsum.com\/feed\/html","c_date":"2014-04-22 12:53:17","summary":"","owner_first":"Joffin","owner":"Joffin Joy","owner_id":"ZGN0AQZ9ac3K","owner_type":"FH5R","photo":"http:\/\/localhost\/4thUser_v4\/images\/getuserphoto\/ZGN0AQZ9ac3K\/1\/small\/10443_1395738251_usr_crop.jpg","lc_cnt":[{"like":"0","comment":"7"}],"ckt_name":{"ZwVk":"Trainees"},"comments":{"ZwVk":[{"uc_id":"AQL2Aj=9ac3K","uc_c_date":"2014-04-22 13:07:42","uc_m_date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","comment":"","comment_type":"1","sender_type":"0","user_id":"ZGNkZwH9ac3K","display_name":"User Jolly","u_type":"FH5R","photo":"http:\/\/localhost\/4thUser_v4\/images\/getuserphoto\/ZGNkZwH9ac3K\/1\/small\/10125_1398517242_usr_crop.JPG","like_cnt":"0"},{"uc_id":"AQL2BN=9ac3K","uc_c_date":"2014-04-22 13:08:09","uc_m_date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","comment":"","comment_type":"1","sender_type":"0","user_id":"ZGNkZwH9ac3K","display_name":"User Jolly","u_type":"FH5R","photo":"http:\/\/localhost\/4thUser_v4\/images\/getuserphoto\/ZGNkZwH9ac3K\/1\/small\/10125_1398517242_usr_crop.JPG","like_cnt":"0"},{"uc_id":"AQL2BD=9ac3K","uc_c_date":"2014-04-22 13:10:06","uc_m_date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","comment":"","comment_type":"1","sender_type":"0","user_id":"ZGNkZwH9ac3K","display_name":"User Jolly","u_type":"FH5R","photo":"http:\/\/localhost\/4thUser_v4\/images\/getuserphoto\/ZGNkZwH9ac3K\/1\/small\/10125_1398517242_usr_crop.JPG","like_cnt":"0"}]}},{"id":"ZGRlZGL9ac3K","type":1,"title":"sample postApr 21 22014...edited sxdsdasdasdasdasdasdd\r\n\r\nLorem ipsum .","feed":{"is_img":0},"c_date":"2014-04-21 17:19:19","owner":"Joffin Joy","owner_first":"Joffin","owner_id":"ZGN0AQZ9ac3K","owner_type":"FH5R","photo":"http:\/\/localhost\/4thUser_v4\/images\/getuserphoto\/ZGN0AQZ9ac3K\/1\/small\/10443_1395738251_usr_crop.jpg","lc_cnt":null,"ckt_name":{"ZwVk":"Trainees"}},{"id":"ZGNlZGD9ac3K","type":2,"title":"sample event Apr 21 2014.....","desc":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas adipiscing diam elit, ac pharetra magna rhoncus id. Quisque placerat imperdiet dolor in varius.","st_date":"Apr 21, 2014","st_time":"20:30:00","end_date":"May 14, 2014","end_time":"15:00:00","location":"Long Beach, CA, United States","c_date":"2014-04-21 17:15:10","owner_first":"Joffin","owner":"Joffin Joy","owner_id":"ZGN0AQZ9ac3K","owner_type":"FH5R","photo":"http:\/\/localhost\/4thUser_v4\/images\/getuserphoto\/ZGN0AQZ9ac3K\/1\/small\/10443_1395738251_usr_crop.jpg","lc_cnt":null,"ckt_name":{"ZwVk":"Trainees"}},{"id":"ZGNkBQx9ac3K","type":2,"title":"evnt on 17th april(edited)","desc":"","st_date":"Jan 02, 2010","st_time":"10:05:00","end_date":"Apr 17, 2014","end_time":"10:05:00","location":"Mobile, AL, United States","c_date":"2014-04-17 10:05:28","owner_first":"Sanesh","owner":"Sanesh Sunny","owner_id":"ZGNjBQN9ac3K","owner_type":"FH5R","photo":"http:\/\/localhost\/4thUser_v4\/images\/getuserphoto\/ZGNjBQN9ac3K\/1\/small\/noimage-ind.jpg","lc_cnt":[{"like":"1","comment":"3"}],"ckt_name":{"ZwVk":"Trainees"},"comments":{"ZwVk":[{"uc_id":"AQLjZD=9ac3K","uc_c_date":"2014-04-17 11:07:42","uc_m_date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","comment":"sdsds","comment_type":"1","sender_type":"0","user_id":"ZGR9ac3K","display_name":"User User Technologies Pvt Ltd","u_type":"D09F","photo":"http:\/\/localhost\/4thUser_v4\/images\/getuserphoto\/ZGR9ac3K\/1\/small\/1398519087_11.jpg","like_cnt":"0"},{"uc_id":"AQLkZN=9ac3K","uc_c_date":"2014-04-17 11:44:35","uc_m_date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","comment":"sdfsdfsdfsdf","comment_type":"1","sender_type":"0","user_id":"ZGNjAmD9ac3K","display_name":"Herald Charley","u_type":"FH5R","photo":"http:\/\/localhost\/4thUser_v4\/images\/getuserphoto\/ZGNjAmD9ac3K\/1\/small\/10074_1398168441_usr_lr.","like_cnt":"0"},{"uc_id":"AQLkZD=9ac3K","uc_c_date":"2014-04-17 11:44:45","uc_m_date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","comment":"sdfsdfsdfsdf","comment_type":"1","sender_type":"0","user_id":"ZGNjAmD9ac3K","display_name":"Herald Charley","u_type":"FH5R","photo":"http:\/\/localhost\/4thUser_v4\/images\/getuserphoto\/ZGNjAmD9ac3K\/1\/small\/10074_1398168441_usr_lr.","like_cnt":"0"}]}},{"id":"ZGRkAmN9ac3K","type":1,"title":"test post by sanesh on 16th april and shared with trainees ckt","feed":{"is_img":0},"c_date":"2014-04-16 14:10:56","owner":"Sanesh Sunny","owner_first":"Sanesh","owner_id":"ZGNjBQN9ac3K","owner_type":"FH5R","photo":"http:\/\/localhost\/4thUser_v4\/images\/getuserphoto\/ZGNjBQN9ac3K\/1\/small\/noimage-ind.jpg","lc_cnt":[{"like":"0","comment":"1"}],"ckt_name":{"ZwVk":"Trainees"}},{"id":"ZGRkAmD9ac3K","type":1,"title":"edited","feed":{"is_img":0},"c_date":"2014-04-16 14:21:23","owner":"Sanesh Sunny","owner_first":"Sanesh","owner_id":"ZGNjBQN9ac3K","owner_type":"FH5R","photo":"http:\/\/localhost\/4thUser_v4\/images\/getuserphoto\/ZGNjBQN9ac3K\/1\/small\/noimage-ind.jpg","lc_cnt":[{"like":"0","comment":"9"}],"ckt_name":{"ZwVk":"Trainees"},"comments":{"ZwVk":[{"uc_id":"AQH3BD=9ac3K","uc_c_date":"2014-04-16 15:31:41","uc_m_date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","comment":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam et malesuada libero. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. ","comment_type":"1","sender_type":"0","user_id":"ZGNjBQN9ac3K","display_name":"Sanesh Sunny","u_type":"FH5R","photo":"http:\/\/localhost\/4thUser_v4\/images\/getuserphoto\/ZGNjBQN9ac3K\/1\/small\/noimage-ind.jpg","like_cnt":"0"},{"uc_id":"AQH4Aj=9ac3K","uc_c_date":"2014-04-16 18:42:38","uc_m_date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","comment":"","comment_type":"1","sender_type":"0","user_id":"ZGNjBQN9ac3K","display_name":"Sanesh Sunny","u_type":"FH5R","photo":"http:\/\/localhost\/4thUser_v4\/images\/getuserphoto\/ZGNjBQN9ac3K\/1\/small\/noimage-ind.jpg","like_cnt":"0"}]}},{"id":"ZGNjAmx9ac3K","type":6,"title":"Sample Talk Added Apr 14 2014.....","desc":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In posuere elit odio, vel interdum ligula pretium vitae. Praesent eu orci non ipsum euismod mollis. ","c_date":"2014-04-14 18:34:44","author_name":"Sanesh Sunny","about_author":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In posuere elit odio,","authorId":"ZGNjBQN9ac3K","owner_first":"Joffin","owner":"Joffin Joy","owner_id":"ZGN0AQZ9ac3K","owner_type":"FH5R","photo":"http:\/\/localhost\/4thUser_v4\/images\/getuserphoto\/ZGN0AQZ9ac3K\/1\/small\/10443_1395738251_usr_crop.jpg","author_photo":"http:\/\/localhost\/4thUser_v4\/images\/getuserphoto\/ZGNjBQN9ac3K\/1\/small\/noimage-ind.jpg","lc_cnt":null,"ckt_name":{"ZwVk":"Trainees"}},{"id":"ZGRjAGR9ac3K","type":1,"title":"I amsdsdsdsdsd co-founder ofsdsdsds da","feed":{"is_img":0},"c_date":"2014-03-08 07:47:22","owner":"User Jolly","owner_first":"User","owner_id":"ZGNkZwH9ac3K","owner_type":"FH5R","photo":"http:\/\/localhost\/4thUser_v4\/images\/getuserphoto\/ZGNkZwH9ac3K\/1\/small\/10125_1398517242_usr_crop.JPG","lc_cnt":[{"like":"1","comment":"0"}],"ckt_name":{"ZGD3AQZ9ac3K":"Vijayee Bhava"}},{"id":"ZGRjAQx9ac3K","type":1,"title":"Lessons on Self Development\r\nhttp:\/\/localhost\/files\/vijayeebhava\/2\/Vijayeebhava_Lessons_Self_development.pptx\r\n\r\nPrepared by: Sreeja - Phoenix team","feed":{"is_img":0},"c_date":"2014-03-09 10:26:18","owner":"Vijayee Bhava","owner_first":"Vijayee Bhava","owner_id":"AQL2ZwL9ac3K","owner_type":"D09F","photo":"http:\/\/localhost\/4thUser_v4\/images\/getuserphoto\/AQL2ZwL9ac3K\/1\/small\/1394201730_46626.png","lc_cnt":[{"like":"1","comment":"0"}],"ckt_name":{"ZGD3AQH9ac3K":"Vijayee Bhava - II"}},{"id":"ZGNlAmL9ac3K","type":7,"title":"Key Lessons on LEADERSHIP","desc":"https:\/\/localhost\/files\/vijayeebhava\/2\/Vijayeebhava_Leadership_Key_Lessons.docx <\/a>","source":"","c_date":"2014-03-08 20:40:55","summary":"","owner_first":"Anaz","owner":"Anaz Kabeer","owner_id":"ZGNmZQH9ac3K","owner_type":"FH5R","photo":"http:\/\/localhost\/4thUser_v4\/images\/getuserphoto\/ZGNmZQH9ac3K\/1\/small\/10305_1382457349_usr_lr.","lc_cnt":[{"like":"1","comment":"0"}],"ckt_name":{"ZGD3AQH9ac3K":"Vijayee Bhava - II"}},{"id":"ZGNlAmp9ac3K","type":7,"title":"Qualities of an Entrepreneur","desc":"https:\/\/localhost\/files\/vijayeebhava\/2\/Vijayeebhava_Key_Lessons_Qualities_Entrepreneur.docx <\/a>","source":"","c_date":"2014-03-08 20:41:37","summary":"","owner_first":"Anaz","owner":"Anaz Kabeer","owner_id":"ZGNmZQH9ac3K","owner_type":"FH5R","photo":"http:\/\/localhost\/4thUser_v4\/images\/getuserphoto\/ZGNmZQH9ac3K\/1\/small\/10305_1382457349_usr_lr.","lc_cnt":[{"like":"1","comment":"0"}],"ckt_name":{"ZGD3AQH9ac3K":"Vijayee Bhava - II"}}],"tp_likes":"[id=\"tp_like_ZGNlAmL9ac3K_7_T\"],[id=\"tp_like_ZGNlAmp9ac3K_7_T\"],[id=\"tp_like_ZGRjAQx9ac3K_1_T\"],[id=\"tp_like_ZGRlBQR9ac3K_1_T\"]","cmnt_likes":"[id=\"tp_like_ZGRlBQR9ac3K_1_AQp1AN=9ac3K_C\"]","up_next":"2014-03-09 09:14:44","up_start":0,"up_end":"15"}
```

Answer (score 0):

`nalert('hello");"`. The double quote seems to invalid everything after, no ?

EDIT: Ho, as bartek said in his edit, you should try jsonlint. Thanks for the info, bartek.

Comment: is double quote is causing problem.... how to bypass this as we can't force users not to enter double quotes in description,title etc...